# Why static void method() const is compiled error?

Tags: c++

I have an interview, the interviewer asked me a question about const and static keyword in C++; The question is why you cannot define a member function like this:

```
static void func() const
```

He mentions somewhat *this = null causes this problem, I just did not get his idea, he didn't talk in detail.

Comment: `*this = null` makes no sense and I hope he did not say exactly that.

Comment: If he mentioned that `this` doesn't exist at all (rather than being null), that might give you a clue as to why `const` makes no sense there.

Comment: A toy use of `*this = nullptr` (https://ideone.com/ZY25V5). :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 This is funny but probably confusing here.  I'll add another `;-)`.  Unrelated and probably unimportant: your assignment operator is missing a `return` statement.

Comment: Some people that are used to Java might be confused by the fact that when invoking a static method reflectively in Java, it is convention to pass `null` as the first argument to [`java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) but this is merely an obscurity of the reflection API and does not mean that a static method gets passed `null` as `this` pointer which would be really useless.  And anyway, C++ is not Java.

Comment: Basically the idea is that every class member function is actually compiled from `A::Func() => Func(A *this)`. Thus, when you put the const keyword infront of a function the compiler turns `A::Func() const` => `Func(const A* this)`. Since func() isn't a member function of a class it doesn't have a **this** pointer, which means that the compiler has no clue what do with the const keyword because it's an invalid usage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trailing `const` qualifier is applied to the `this` pointer that is passed as an implicit argument to each non-`static` member function.  Since the function in question is `static`, there is no `this` pointer that could be qualified so the construct is bogus.

Answer (score 3):

The `const` keyword is used to prevent you from modifying the object that the method is called against. Static methods aren't called against an object, so it doesn't make sense to include them both.

Answer (score 3):

`static` indicates that the method is a *class method* and does not operate on a particular instance of that class.

`const` indicates that the method operates on constant instances of that class.

As `static` does not operate on instances and `const` operates on instances, they cannot both apply.